# rename all files of a specific type in a directory

Tags: bash, rename

I am trying to use `bash` to rename all `.txt` files in a directory that match a specific pattern. My two attempts below have removed the files from the directory and threw an error.  Thank you :)

**input**

```
16-0000_File-A_variant_strandbias_readcount.vcf.hg19_multianno_dbremoved_removed_final_index_inheritence_import.txt
16-0002_File-B_variant_strandbias_readcount.vcf.hg19_multianno_dbremoved_removed_final_index_inheritence_import.txt
```

**desired output**

```
16-0000_File-A_multianno.txt
16-0002_File-B_multianno.txt
```

Bash attempt 1 `this removes the files from the directory`

```
for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/test/vcf/overall/annovar/*_classify.txt ; do
 # Grab file prefix.
 p=${f%%_*_}
 bname=`basename $f`
 pref=${bname%%.txt}
 mv "$f" ${p}_multianno.txt
done
```

Bash attempt 2 `Substitution replacement not terminated at (eval 1) line 1.`

```
for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/test/vcf/overall/annovar/*_classify.txt ; do
 # Grab file prefix.
 p=${f%%_*_}
 bname=`basename $f`
 pref=${bname%%.txt}
 rename -n 's/^$f/' *${p}_multianno.txt
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop. `rename` alone can do this:

```
rename -n 's/(.*?_[^_]+).*/${1}_multianno.txt/g' /home/cmccabe/Desktop/test/vcf/overall/annovar/*_classify.txt
```

The meaning of the regular expression is roughly,
*capture everything from the start until the 2nd `_`,
match the rest,
and replace with the captured prefix and append `_multianno.txt`*

With the `-n` flag, this command will print what it would do without actually doing it.
When the output looks good, remove the `-n` and rerun.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great help and explanation, I appreciate them :)